# What does 相手 mean in 「素直な自分をぶつけられる相手」?

Tags: grammar, translation

I'm confused about how to describe 相手 here. I don't know if it's “partner who can show their true self” or “partner to whom can show your true self”. Also, is the ぶつけられる here like ぶつけることができる?

> 「素直な自分をぶつけられる**相手**を、さなや自分が出来るなら、喜んでしてあげたかった」

[Here's a screenshot](http://piccy.info/view3/4514387/f6e7ab7ff0f4102f040cf23705a29af4/orig/) for more context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

相手 doesn't necessarily translate to "partner". Here it's more like 相手 in [話]{はな}し相手, "someone (to talk to)." →　[話し相手](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E8%A9%B1%E3%81%97%E7%9B%B8%E6%89%8B)
The sentence can be rephrased as

> アイリちゃんが素直な自分をぶつけられる人(or友達)に、サナや俺がなれるなら、喜んでなってあげたかった。
>   アイリちゃんが言いたいことを素直に言えるような人(or友達)に、サナや俺がなれるなら、喜んでなってあげたかった。
>  
>   (I and サナ would have gladly been the ones to whom アイリちゃん could show her true self.)

The ぶつけられる here means the same as ぶつけることができる. (The られる is the potential auxiliary verb, not passive or honorific.)

Answer (score 1):

"られる" has different meanings (be able to, used to polite expression, someone's act to our side) depend on the context as you know, In this case, "Sana and I would like to be the partner who accept Airi's true self".

Comment: IOW: It is a "Partner to whom [one] can show your true self" (but thanks for the translation.) .....it is not really a 相手, more about distinguishing between the potential and the passive / polite form (られる／尊敬語）